# What would someone saying ... ンなこと mean?

Tags: translation, phrases

I assume it's some alternative for 'nevermind'?

> ・・・ンなこと
>   いーからさっさと
>   帰ろーぜっ

[image]

Answer (score 5):

んなこと is just an abbreviated form of そんなこと

Answer (score 1):

…ンなこと is the *same* as そんなこと. そんなこと means "about that".
In English, 気にする is "worry". So the translation is:

> Don't worry about that.